# Sum the values in Excel cells depending on changing criteria

Tags: excel, sumifs

In an Excel spread sheet I have three columns of data, the first column A is a unique identifier. Column B is a number and column C is either a tick or a space:

```
      A          B          C
1    d-45       150         √
2    d-46       200
3    d-45        80 
4    d-46        20         √
5    d-45        70         √
```

Now, I wish to sum the values in column B depending on a tick being present and also relative to the unique ID in column A. In this case rows 1 and 5. Identifying the tick I use

```
=IF(ISTEXT(C1),CONCATENATE(A1))
```

&

```
=IF(ISTEXT(C1),CONCATENATE(B1)).
```

This leaves me with two arrays of data:

```
      D          E                            
1   d-45        150                                                     
4   d-46         20                            
5   d-45         70
```

I now want to sum the values in column E depending on the ID in column D, in this case row 1 and 5. I can use a straight forward `SUMIFS` statement to specify `d-45` as the criteria however this unique ID will always change. Is there a variation of `SUMIFS` I can use?

I also wish to put each new variation of ID number into a separate header with the summed totals underneath, that is:

```
       A         B 
1   d-45      d-46
2    220        20
```

etc...

Comment: [Pivot Table](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/datamanagementinexcel/ss/8912pivot_table.htm)?

Comment: Pivot table will own this hardcore, agree with simoco. Especially that header stuff at the end.

Comment: Yes that may work, however I would like the end result or the sum total relative to each ID to be updated automaticaly  every time a tick is added on a seperate spreadsheet. Can I do this with a pivot table?

Comment: OK Pivot table it is>>

Comment: @SaranJackson You can 'refresh' the pivot table as and when needed. You might also want the Pivot Data Source to be long so that you will also capture new inserted rows. The only drawback with that method could be that you will have `(blank)` in the last row of the pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

To get the distinct ID's write (in H1 then copy right):
This one is an array formula so you need Ctrl Shift Enter to enter the formula

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$5;SMALL(IF(ROW($A$1:$A$5)-ROW($A$1)+1=MATCH($A$1:$A$5;$A$1:$A$5;0);ROW($A$1:$A$5)-ROW($A$1)+1;"");COLUMNS($A$1:A1)))
```

Now to get the sum (H2 and copy right)

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$5=H1)*ISTEXT($C$1:$C$5)*$B$1:$B$5)
```

Data in the example is in A1:C5
Depending on your regional settings you may need to replace ";" field separator by ","

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SUMIFS
=SUMIFS(B1:B5,A1:A5,"=d-45",C1:C5,"<>")
```

where `"<>"` means that the cell is not empty...